# I have troubles with implementing recursion in this task

Tags: python, oop, recursion, binary-tree

I'm dealing with binary trees. I have `class Tree` and I want to write method `sum()` that returns sum of all numbers in the tree. This is what I've written:

```
def sum(self):
    s = self.n
    if self.left == None and self.right == None:
        return
    elif self.left == None and self.right != None:
        s = s + self.right.sum()
    elif self.left != None and self.right == None:
        s = s + self.left.sum()
    else:
        s = s + self.right.sum()
        s = s + self.left.sum()
    return s
```

But it doesn't work and I'm stuck here. How should I implement recursion in this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails because your initial `return` is missing a value.

Apart from that, your function contains a lot of redundancy which can be removed, leaving us with:

```
def sum(self):
    s = self.n
    if self.right != None:
        s += self.right.sum()
    if self.left != None:
        s += self.left.sum()
    return s
```